# jQuery Unbind() everything within a Function?

Tags: jquery, events, unbind

So I have a function like

```
function onLoadMe() {
 //stuff in function
}
```

And a second function

```
function onLoadMeSecond() {
     //stuff in function
    }
```

I want to try and bind the `onLoadMe()` on the page load, but then unbind everything in `onLoadMe()` and load the second function `onLoadMeSecond()` for the element ?

i.e.

```
jQuery('#some-id').click(function() {
   jQuery(this).unbind(onLoadMe());
   onLoadMeSecond();
});
```

How can I do this as the above doesn't work ?

Edit: See example http://jsfiddle.net/cer9R/5/

Comment: There's a problem in the logic flow in your jsfiddle sample. What are you trying to do exactly in your code?

Comment: Not sure what the logic problem is = look @ http://jsfiddle.net/cer9R/5/ - basically, `onLoad()` should load and if I click `test3` then it should `unbind(onLoad)` and show `test2` ? But it doesnt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is `$(window).unbind('load',onLoadMe)`.

Though in the JsFiddle example you are binding a handler on document ready, not page load. To unbind that, you could use `$(document).unbind('ready')`. Of course, using the document ready event to bind a click handler which would unbind the (already finished) document ready handler makes no sense at all.

Comment: legend - seems to work :-) See @ http://jsfiddle.net/cer9R/8/ - however it does seem that you can still click `#test` and it works ? i.e. the click event is not unbind ?

Comment: Well if you are trying to unbind the click handler, you should use `$('#test').unbind('click')`. I understood your question to be about unbinding the load handler.

Comment: well I want to actually unbind everything that is contained within the `onLoad` ? i.e. regardless if it is a click or not ?

Comment: If you want to unbind lots of handlers from a simple element, you can use namespaces for that: `$('#foo').bind('click.onload'); $('#foo').bind('focus.onload'); $('#foo').unbind('.onload');` (unbinds everything that ended with `.onload`). Otherwise, the simplest way is probably creating some sort of event registry - a global variable where you store your event handlers so you can unbind them later. But if you need something like that, chances are you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

did u try write like this?

```
 jQuery(this).unbind("onLoadMe");
```

or maybe just this

```
 jQuery(this).unbind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `()` from the unbind parameter:

```
jQuery('#some-id').click(function() {
   jQuery(this).unbind(onLoadMe);
   onLoadMeSecond();
});
```

**`onLoadMe`** instead of `onLoadMe()`

Comment: Correct -- you are calling the function instead of providing a pointer to the function.

Comment: @Makram @Soren - the problem seems to be that I get an error. i.e. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/cer9R/1/ - with Firebug in FF ? You can see the error generated is like `types.split is not a function`

Comment: What? That's not at all how [.bind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) works. Your should pass it an event type, or an event object. And load events are bound on the `window` object anyway.